# How can parse response okhttp3 in xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I using okhttp3 to access rest api in xamarin.android:

```
  Response response = await client.NewCall(request).ExecuteAsync();
            string body = await response.Body().StringAsync() ;
            var jsonres = new JObject(body);
            if (jsonres.ContainsKey("access_token"))
            {
                var accesstoken = jsonres.GetValue("access_token");

            }
```

but at row :   `var jsonres = new JObject(body);`

occur error:

```
Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.
```

In Android studio, this code working ok.
But in Xamarin.android can't parse:
How can parse response okhttp3 in xamarin android?